# What are different values for Allowed Controllers in System Services API key for GraphQL?

Tags: jss, graphql

I'm working on `Sitecore 10.0` `graphQL` and trying to secure the `endpoint` by enabling `PublicService` using `Authentication` and `Sc_api key`. While applying security hardening I came across `allowed controllers in system-> services-> api key`. What is the purpose of `Allowed Controllers` and what is a best practice for `graphQL` to have this value. Is it fine to keep All `(*)` or we need specific controller to be added here as shown in below screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the [official documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/create-a-sitecore-api-key.html) for more detail but the long and short of it is you can create a safelist of controllers. You can use `*` however it is best practice to explicitly add your controllers to the list. If you have multiple controllers, you can add them to a new line and end the line with a `;` character like so:

```
Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc.Controllers.LayoutServiceController; 
Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Globalization.Controllers.DictionaryServiceController; 
Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.Mvc.GraphQLController;
GraphQL:/api/yourappname
```